# Header files are not found while archiving the build in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a sub project that has been developed as dynamic lib and included that sub project into my main project and been set as target dependency.

When I run my main project, **.a** file for my sub project has been created successfully and the corresponding header files are created in the build directory such as (**build/release-iphoneos/include**). I have mentioned path using **MACRO**

In my main project, I mentioned header search path as the same that i mentioned above using **MACRO**.

But when I try to archive the build it throws the run time error file not found in the import statement

```
#import <subproject/myfile.h>
```

But it is getting build and run successfully even though it displays the file not found error in the xcode editor in compile time.

My question is

**Is this because of the build directory will be empty while archieving?**

Comment: How exactly have you set the paths? What is the exact error?

Comment: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)

Comment: where you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as below

**1. The header files were private so changed them as public so they are exposed to main project. (To build & run successfully)**

**2. I copied the header files and created a directory and add them into my main project and set the header search path to point that directory (To archive successfully)**